# Animate a pin pushed out of a wall

Tags: animation

The scenario is quite simple: a pin (cylinder) sticks in a thin wall (cube with a cutout hole for the pin, done by boolean modyfier). This pin will be hit by a hammer (cube) and should then move according to physics in the way hitted and by gravity. Therefore I make the pin a rigid body, active and dynamic, right? But now the problem: to let the pin stick in the wall (until hit by the hammer) I make the wall a rigid body too. But whatever options I tried until now, pin an wall "jump away" from each other as soon as the simulation starts or the pin falls through the wall. What to do, so that the pin is not affected by the wall (except that it is carried by the wall)?

Comment: PS: The possible answer: keep the nail "not dynamic" until it is hit by the hammer. But even then the nails direction of movement is not the desired on (out of the wall in the direction of the movement of the hammer), instead the "interaction" with the wall then let the nail fly away in a wrong direction (and the wall too).

Comment: if you can attach an example .blend (blend-exchange or pasteall or else). It could also be the shape type (bounds) and the two being too near (collision margin also counts)

Comment: Sometimes scaling the whole thing up in size will give you more reliable behavior with collision physics. Remember to Apply Scale.